# Extract values from another HTML in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am developing WP8 browser check app. The App loads the below HTML pages in this order:

1. ***A.html*** that fades an Image several times, calculates(and displays) Frame rate.
2. ***B.html*** that zooms in/out a pre-written text, calculate Speed(and displays) and other attributes.

Both of these work fine. I now need to load a RESULTANT page(***C.HTML***) that should **extract** calculated scores from both A.html and B.html and display scores in tabular format.

To save content(in a temp file) i used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () 
  {
    var sw : StreamWriter = new StreamWriter("HTML_Results.txt");
    sr.Write('xyz");

    //calculations done here
    sr.Write (result);
  }
</script>
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. There is no syntax error, but text file after execution is empty.

I would like to know if this is the best way to extract values from html pages. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () 
{
  var sw : StreamWriter = new StreamWriter("HTML_Results.txt");
  sr.Write('xyz',true);

  //calculations done here
  sr.Write (result,true);
  //close streamwriter
  sr.Close();
}
</script>
```

Maybe a copy paste error but the xyz was misquoted with one single and one double.

You are also leaving off the boolean which tells StreamWriter whether or not to overwrite.

And dont forget to close.

```
 sr.Write('xyz',true);
```

Comment: No Syntax error. But App is misbehaving leaving the HTML page unloaded/blank. If i comment StreamWriter section, it functions normally.